# __setattr__ class decorator python

Tags: python, decorator, setattr

I'm using a class decorator but I didn't understand how set attribute with **setattr**, this is my code:

```
def cldecor(*par):
    def onDecorator(aClass):
        class wrapper:
            def __init__(self, *args): 
                self.wrapped = aClass(*args)
            def __getattr__(self, name): 
                return getattr(self.wrapped, name)
            def __setattr__(self, attribute, value): 
                if attribute == 'wrapped': 
                    self.__dict__[attribute] = value 
                else:
                    setattr(self.wrapped, attribute, value)
        return wrapper
    return onDecorator


@cldecor('data','size')
class Doubler:
    def __init__(self,label,start):
        self.label = label
        self.data = start

    def display(self):
        print('{0} => {1}'.format(self.label, self.data))
```

but when i do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    X = Doubler('X is ', [1,2,3])
    X.xxx = [3,4,9]
    print(X.xxx)
    X.display()
```

i have this output:

```
[3, 4, 9]
X is  => [1, 2, 3]
```

how can i do for having this output?

```
[3, 4, 9]
X is  => [3, 4, 9]
```

Comment: Maybe explain what you think this is supposed to achieve?

Comment: What does `*par` do in your code? You leave it unused...

Comment: Your code as posted does not generate the output you show. The output I get is `'[3, 4, 9]\n
X is  => [1, 2, 3]'`

Comment: ok i change my output, but the problem remains

Comment: @fege, when you write or edit a question, don't mess up the indentation. Select your code, and use the `{}` button at the top of the edit box to format it. It will do everything for you.

Comment: Unless you are using Python 3 there, inherit your classes from "object" - since you are using advanced class features, you might encounter a lot of misbehavior if not using new style classess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `display` method only prints the data in `self.data`, but you've created an attribute caled `xxx`. Of course `display` doesn't display it. This works:

```
>>> X.data = [3,4,9]
>>> X.display()
X is  => [3, 4, 9]
```